# How does boost b2 determine which filename for libs to use?

Tags: c++, git, github, boost

The question is in the topic.

My practical issue is that I have checked out the github boost project. When building, it creates, e.g., `libboost_date_time_vc140-mt-1_65_1.lib` because it is boost 1.65.1. This one is correct but `config/version.php` sets versions 1.65.0.

Obviously, there is a mismatch because when including the boost headers, it will try to link against `libboost_date_time_vc140-mt-1_65.lib` which does not exist.

So, my question would be where `b2` gets its filename information from or what I might have done wrong?!

Comment: The link pragma should be generated in config/auto_link.hpp. You can start from there

Comment: It is generated there, when I include something, but also at `b2`? I do not think so because `b2` generates different lib names... I have explained exactly what is generated and how it differs

Comment: You probably checked out an in-development version. Looks like the super-project and config module are somewhat out of sync: [\[1\]](https://github.com/boostorg/config/commit/b8fe4fe5e0ac0b0ef3d37022749193a634f86ece)  [\[2\]](https://github.com/boostorg/boost/commit/13cc3507fbcc12a95654b23a1a1b521837deeb48#diff-5cecbe9cda25620173d84b5f6efa6690). You've got the source, fix it.

Comment: @DanMašek Ah, thank you! So, precisely `jamroot` (used for building b2) and `config/version.h` are out of sync; that I understand